# passwd: Authentication token manipulation error

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, pam, passwd, shadow

I am running a Ubuntu 12 machine, and have recently been working to secure it.  I made all the changes from [this](https://library.linode.com/securing-your-server) guide.  I am not running a Linode, but I used these as a starting point for setting up the firewall and such.

All went smoothly, and I have been using the machine for some time now.  I tried to lock some users' accounts, with the `passwd -l` command, and that was successful.  However, when I try to add a new user, or change my password, I have the strangest error:

```
myuser@mymachine:~$ passwd 
Old Password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Or, when adding a new user:

```
myuser@mymachine:~$ sudo adduser mynewuser
Adding user `mynewuser' ...
Adding new group `mynewuser' (1011) ...
Adding new user `mynewuser' (1002) with group `mynewuser' ...
Creating home directory `/home/mynewuser' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
Try again? [y/N]
```

I searched for this error, and the vast majority of problems were solved by remounting / as read and write.  However, this is not the problem, as it is mounted as read and write (I confirmed).  Note that the same error is encountered from different users, and from root trying to change other users' passwords.

Do you have any insight as to why I am (seemingly spontaneously) getting this error?  I have not done any manual editing of the `shadow` or `passwd` files--or really made any change to user authentication at all.

In case it is relevant:

```
ls -lh /etc/passwd -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.2K Jul 23 17:26 /etc/passwd 
ls -lh /etc/shadow -rw------- 1 root shadow 3.1K Jul 23 17:20 /etc/shadow
```

Comment: In case it is relevant:
myuser@mymachine:~$ ls -lh /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.2K Jul 23 17:26 /etc/passwd
myuser@mymachine:~$ ls -lh /etc/shadow
-rw------- 1 root shadow 3.1K Jul 23 17:20 /etc/shadow

Comment: Did you created the user "myuser" later? He should be in the group "sudo". Take a look at /etc/group.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurred due to incorrect permissions set to **/usr/bin/passwd**.

Please try to set the permissions as 4511.

You can update the permissions using  the command:

`chmod 4511 /usr/bin/passwd`

This will resolve the issue.

Comment: It would be useful if your answer mentioned the purpose of the **setuid** bit and why (for what purpose) this needs to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Login as root on terminal and execute below command

```
# pam-auth-update
```

Now Select "YES" as mentioned in this screenprint:

[image]

Next select create home directory on login using down arrow key and space bar in key board and click ok as mentioned in this screenprint: